# change a field depending an a value

Tags: jquery, input

Lets say I have a selectbox wit 10 predefined amounts and an option "other". If I select "other" i get an input box to give the amount. When I leave that field i wnat the value of the selecbox to be the amount typed in the input box. How would I do that with jquery?

Comment: do you mean a dropdownlist with 10 predefined amounts and when you say input box, you mean textbox?

Comment: @sanders- you need to learn how SO(StackOverflow) works as you continue to ask question...when you receive a correct answer that you are pleased with you should mark as accepted. That is what the "check" sign by the answers are there for.

Comment: you don't need to submit your own answer saying, 
ex: that answer works for me Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that 'selectbox' is equivalent to an HTML 'select' tag.
here 'otherInpute' is a text input box and 'someSelect' is a HTML 'select' tag.

```
var val = $("#otherInput").val();
$("#someSelect option:selected").text(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this so when you leave the input a new option is created in the select box:

```
$("input#other-value").blur(function (){
    // Create new option
    $("<option>") 
        // Assign value and text
        .val($(this).val())
        .text($(this).val())
        // Append before the "other" option
        .insertBefore("select@select-id option[value=other]");
});
```

Also, please mark answers that satisfies you as "accepted" with the check at the left. If you don't, questions are left open and nobody knows the real answer.

Comment: well the value doesn't have to be visible in the select box. 
I thought something like:

$("#otheramount").blur(function(){
 $("#ppsub_amount").val() = $("#otheramount").val();
     
});
but firebug gives the error: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: You have to do something like this: $("#ppsub_amount").val( $("#otheramount").val() ). Note that val() returns a value, but sets a new one when passed as parameter; you can't assign a value to a function's result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $("#otherInput").val();
```

$("#someSelect option:selected").text(val)